# Maximum & minimum values of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am to check for max & min values for the given function $$f(x, y, z) = xy^2z^3$$ which is defined on $$M = \left\{x, y, z > 0, x+2y+3z=6\right\}$$

So.. what I did is:

$F(x, y, z, \gamma) = xy^2z^3 - \gamma(x+2y+3z-6)$ therefore
$\begin{cases} \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = y^2z^3 - \gamma = 0\\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}  = 2xyz^3-2\gamma = 0\\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} = 3xy^2z^2 -3\gamma = 0\\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial \gamma} = -x-2y-3z+6 = 0\\ \end{cases}$

After the calculation I get the possible point is $P = (1, 1, 1)$.
So I count the 2nd derivatives : 
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = 0 &\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} = 2yz^3 &\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial z} = 3y^2z^2 \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} = 2yz^3 &\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = 2xz^3 &\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial z} = 6xyz^2 \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z \partial x} = 3y^2z^2 &\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z \partial y} = 6xyz^2 &\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2} = 6xy^2z 
\end{array}\right]$$

So with our point P it looks like :
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&2&3\\
2&2&6\\
3&6&6
\end{array}\right]$$

And here's where I got lost. $\det_{1} = 0$ therefore we have no idea whether there is an extremum or not, but Wolfram says there's a local maximum in $(1, 1, 1)$. How should I obtain it?

Comment: Skip this comment -- you _wrote_ $F$ in your Hessian, but _did_ use $f$...

Comment: isnt it what i did?

Comment: Yes, it just isn't what you typed... but check your determinant again -- it isn't zero.

Comment: How come its not? $det_{1} = \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2} = 0$

Comment: That's what I got: the second cofactor _isn't_ 0 .

Comment: $det_{1} = 0, det_{2} = -4, det_{3} = 12$ isnt it like that?

Comment: I'm getting the same matrix you do, but I'm not finding an example of a problem with similar results.  The matrix has one positive and two _complex_ eigenvalues (with negative real parts).  The matrix doesn't appear to be "negative-definite", so this doesn't seem like the critical point ought to be a local maximum.

Comment: I was reviewing the work and found a typo in the Hessian.  However, it only changes $ \ \det_3 \ $ to 30 and the eigenvalues are now one real positive and two real negative, so there is no material change to be made in the remarks on this critical point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon poking around a bit more, it looks like having **H** = 0 (what you call $ \ \det_1 \ $ ) is one of those situations where the standard "second derivative test" for three variables can't be applied.  We *can* fall back on substituting the constraint into the function to produce

$$h(y,z) \ = \ (6 - 2y - 3z)  \cdot  y^2  \cdot  z^3 \ = \ 6y^2z^3 \ - \ 2y^3z^3 \ - \ 3y^2z^4 , $$

for which the discriminant is

**[EDIT]**

$$D \ |_{(1,1)} \ = \ [ \ h_{yy} \ h_{zz} \ - \ (h_{yz})^2 \ ] \ |_{(1,1)} $$

$$= \ [ \ (12z^3 - 12yz^3 - 6z^4)\cdot (36y^2z \ - 12y^3z \ - 36y^2z^2) $$
$$ - \ (36yz^2 - 18y^2z^2 - 24yz^3)^2 \ ]  \ |_{(1,1)} $$

$$ = \ (-6)(-12) \ - \ (-6)^2 \ = \ 36 \ > \ 0  \ . $$

Since $ \ h_{yy} \ |_{(1,1)}  =  -6 \ < 0  \ , $ this identifies this critical point as a local maximum in $ \ x \ $ under the constraint.

The constraint surface is a bit peculiar, as this maximum sits atop a rather narrow "ridge" near a very deep "drop-off" (if one may discuss the "terrain" of the function).  This may explain the difficulty in applying the usual test.  Below are two views of $ \ x = h(y,z) \ $ .

[image]

[I am making this revision as I found an error in a coefficient of one of the second derivatives since my original posting.  There was also a typo in the Hessian matrix in OP's post, but this proved to be immaterial to the overall problem.]

Comment: As I found out, when there are limitations put to the domain of a function, we dont have to check each of the determinant, just the determinant of the whole matrix, which is $>0$ therefore we've got an extremum here. Thanks for your work on the subject!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lagrange multiplier method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) and here is the answer provided by CAS

$$ [x=6-3\,z,y=0,z=z,\lambda_{{1}}=0,x{y}^{2}{z}^{3}=0]$$
$$[x=-2\,y+6,y=y,z=0,\lambda_{{1}}=0,x{y}^{2}{z}^{3}=0]$$
$$[x=1,y=1,z=1,\lambda_{{1}}=1,x{y}^{2}{z}^{3}=1].$$

Comment: The issue isn't getting the critical point (we managed that); it is characterizing the point (1,1,1) using the Hessian.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: I had not seen any one suggested this method. By the way, the title asking for max and min and this is a technique for finding them.

Comment: I'm saying that OP has already found the critical point; they state the point coordinates midway down the paragraph.  (In fact, the method used _is_ a variant of the Lagrange multiplier method: that is how $ \ F(x) \ $ has been defined using $ \ f(x) \ $ .  What they are asking about is that when the Hessian matrix is evaluated there, it doesn't fit the conditions for the "second derivative test" in three variables.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your constraint as $x+y+y+z+z+z=6$ and apply the am/gm inequality, yielding $xy^2z^3\le 1$ ,with equality only when $x=y=z=1$ . The critical point is thus an absolute maximum over the range.